# Let's say I have a list. What's the difference between lst[0] and [lst[0]]?

Tags: python, indexing

I know what lst[x] means in Python, which is basically the element in that index. But i'm not sure what [lst[x]] means.

new to programming btw so go ez

Comment: What's the difference between `thing` and `[thing]`? In the second one, the thing is inside a list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing lst is a python list. lst[x] gives the value contained in list at the index position held in x. Putting square brackets around to give [lst[x]] simply creates a new list with one value, the value obtained from lst.